# iOS Variable names and memory management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am a bit confused by the underscore naming and the self. Is the following code OK?

@interface MyClass()

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString        *name;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString        *surname;

@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize surname = _surname;
```

Then when I need to assign a value I do this

```
self.name = [someParam retain];
```

Answer (score 2):

No this is not ok, since the `self.name` will also retain the value as your declared in the property.

This wil retain:

```
self.name = someParam;
```

Other way the write then same (be aware to release the current var):

```
if (_name != someParam) {
    if(_name) {
       [_name release], _name = nil;
    }
    _name = [someParam retain];
}
```

Comment: The bug in your second version (which shows why you should always use the setter or equivalently assign to the property) is that if _name == someParam already before you start, you run the risk of deallocating someParam.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to repeat the retain :)

just:

```
self.name = someParam;
```

but for the rest I think it's ok

Comment: It's not "you don't have to" but "you must not" otherwise you introduce a memory leak.  +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not right as you have to use the alias _name like

```
if(_name)
{
    [_name release];
    _name=nil;
}
else
{
    //retain the object
}
```